# I'm currently working on a project using the angular 2 . I am getting Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue

Tags: javascript

when i am hitting third party services from my java script code I am getting below error in the browser :

Failed to load http://api.mysite.com: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://client.mysite.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Please suggest me how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

CORS is basically applied by the browsers for security purpose:

If you are using chrome for development you can install this extension:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc

Comment: : Right now I am using this option. But now we have to deploy the same on uat servers there we can't ask users to make the same setup. I want a fix at code level. I have tried many solutions which I got from google in my code but I am getting the same error.

Comment: Which language you have used to write to service?

Answer (score 0):

Download the "Allow-control-allow-origin" Extension from the chrome browser and then enable it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , check your service API has CORS enabled/not. If not enable and check.